# PHP pass-by-reference - is it faster in foreach when you want to change the value in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, pass-by-reference

Is passing by reference **faster** in `foreach` when you want to change the value in the array?

For instance,

```
$a = array (
    0 => array(
        'title' => 'x',
        'content' => 'x',
        'time' => 'x'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'title' => 'x',
        'content' => 'x',
        'time' => 'x'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'title' => 'x',
        'content' => 'x',
        'time' => 'x'
    )
);

function stripData(array $a)
{
    return array(
        'title' => $a['title'],
        'content' => $a['content']
    );
}
```

without reference

```
$b = array();
$begin = microtime(true);
foreach ($a as $v) {
    $b[] = stripData($v);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $begin . "\n"; // 1.38282775879E-5
```

with reference

```
$begin = microtime(true);
foreach ($a as &$v) {
    $v = stripData($v);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $begin . "\n"; // 4.05311584473E-6
```

I tested it on http://phpfiddle.org/ but the #1 seems to be faster while #2 (reference) is a lot slower.

Any ideas?

What would you do in the case like this? Would you do the #1 or #2? Using the reference is less code obviously!

Comment: You've answered your own question. The other pitfall you've missed in option #1 is that you're doubling your memory usage.

Comment: @scrowler  I have tried it like below, `$begin = microtime(true);
$title=array_column($a,'title');
$content=array_column($a,'content');
array_merge_recursive ($title,$content);
$end = microtime(true); `  It take same time **option #2**